# Angular show elements, radio button

Tags: angularjs, scope, radio-button, angularjs-ng-model, ng-show

in Angular I'm doing something like this to show and hide elements when a links is clicked.

```
<a ng-click="showEle = !showEle"><span ng-bind="showEle ? 'Hide' : 'Show'"></span> Element</a>
<div ng-if="showEle">
<div>
```

I need to do something similar but show a div based on a radio button being click.

```
<input type="radio" name="element" value="did" id="">Div One</br>
<input type="radio" name="element" value="did" id="">Div Two</br>
<div>
    Div One
</div>
<div>
    Div two
</div>
```

Both radio buttons are deselected to start then clicking either radio  buttom will show either div.

Comment: Cool. What have you tried? What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `init` scope variable before using it.

```
<input type="radio" name="element" value="did" ng-click="flag = 'div1'">Div One</br>

<input type="radio" name="element" value="did" ng-click="flag = 'div2'" id="">Div Two</br>

<div ng-show="flag == 'div1'">
    Div One
</div>

<div ng-show="flag == 'div2'">
    Div two
</div>
```

To use `ng-model` you need to apply two different values to both the radio button like this.

```
<input type="radio" name="element" ng-value="div1" ng-model="flag">Div One</br>
<input type="radio" name="element" ng-value="div2" ng-model="flag">Div Two</br>

 <div ng-show="flag == 'div1'">
     Div One
 </div>
 <div ng-show="flag == 'div2'">
     Div two
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-model` for the radio button, then put `ng-show` on the `div`s:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  
    <input type="radio" name="element" value="one" id="" ng-model="flag" />Div One<br />

    <input type="radio" name="element" value="two" id="" ng-model="flag" />Div Two<br />

    <div ng-show="flag == 'one'">
        Div One
    </div>

    <div ng-show="flag == 'two'">
        Div two
    </div>
  
</div>
```

the `expression` inside the `ng-show` does a check whether the `flag` is set to the value. If it is, show the div, if not, don't show.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/iBhoJ)

[Reference for ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: What's the meaning of posting an answer even same kind of answer is already there ?

Comment: I saw it first. Sorry, I didn't realize someone answered before I refreshed the page?

Comment: No problem, but there is no meaning of posting an identical answer, if it already posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for. Use ng-model with your radio buttons. Then check the model value on the divs (combined with nd-show).

```
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" class="multiple-option" ng-model="ctrl.selectMsgStatus" ng-value="null" />Red</label>
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" class="multiple-option" ng-model="ctrl.selectMsgStatus" ng-value="true" />Blue</label>
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" class="multiple-option" ng-model="ctrl.selectMsgStatus" ng-value="false" />Green</label>

<div style="background-color:red" ng-show="ctrl.selectMsgStatus == null">Red</div>
<div style="background-color:blue" ng-show="ctrl.selectMsgStatus == true">Blue</div>
<div style="background-color:green" ng-show="ctrl.selectMsgStatus == false">Green</div>
```

I hope it helps!